# ElasticSearch Completion Suggester

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch, I'm using the completion suggester ([docs here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)) with payloads that are very similar to the documents I'm inserting.

My question is - should I be doing this, or only inserting the IDs into the payloads and performing a follow-up Multi-GET to retrieve the real results?  I'd much prefer the latter, but if the former is more performant (even if it takes more memory), I'll stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

The completion suggester was generally implemented with speed as a major factor - to be used in autocomplete fields as you type etc. By increasing the payload you will naturally increase the json response sizes and hence slowdown the whole process.

However, I don't think there is a single right way - its a toolset to be adapted to your specific requirements. If your current solution is more performant, and you can scale to manage the memory requirements, then it sounds like the right solution for you.